# get mongodb model schema in angular controller

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, schema

How to get mongodb model schema as json in angular controller?

I've tried this:

`

```
exports.getSchema = function(res) {
  Info.find().lean().exec(function (err, infos) {
    return res.send(JSON.stringify(infos));
  });
};
```

`

and controller:

`

```
$scope.getSchema = function() {
      $http.get('/infos/schema')
      .success(function(data) {
            $scope.schema = angular.toJson(data);
        });
    };
```

`

but i get `500 internal server error`

`CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "schema" at path "_id"`

what is the correct method?

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(err)` ?

Comment: The error says it all, you have value "schema" for the "_id" key, which should be an ObjectId. You can connect to your database with Robomongo to easily view the data. http://robomongo.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
There is a github repo for this purpose which creates a json out of Mongoose schema [mongoose-schema](https://github.com/stemey/mongoose-schema)

Take a look at: [Google Group of mongoose: Return a mongoose schema as JSON](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongoose-orm/YLDX5f3-LgA)

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting you're trying to use res.send on your req object.

Modify your node function as such:

```
exports.getSchema = function(req, res) {
```